# Number of non-homotopic diffemorphism form a manifold to itself

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

What is the name of this invariant, the number of non-homotopic diffemorphism form a manifold to itself. What is this number for the closed ball B^n, and for euclidean space R^n and for the n-sphere?

Comment: You should specify if you mean "homotopic through diffeomorphisms" or "homotopic through continuous maps". If you mean the second, the answer for $B^n$ and $\Bbb R^n$ is one as they are contractible and for $S^n$ the answer is either two or one depending on the parity of $n$ using the Brouwer degree theorem.

Comment: I dont know which I mean, but wouldnt it be 2 for S^1, but also two for S^2 and S^0? I mean that one map can be deformed to another map. each target point follows a path in the manifoldand no two paths cross.eachother simultaneously.

Comment: Do you mean the [mapping class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group)...?

Comment: Yeas, but the number

Comment: Note that this is very often infinite.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Can you give a simple example?

Comment: Sure. The torus has diffeomorphisms for every 2 by 2 matrix with integer entries and determinant 1. The matrix determines the map on first homology, so different matrices represent non-homotopic maps.

Comment: @Loffen You might be interested in the book "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups" by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit. It is an advanced book, but you can find there a lot of information about mapping class groups. There are also some example computations of the MCG for different surfaces (it is available online).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing (homotopy classes of diffeomorphisms, where in the homotopy "each target point follows a path in the manifold and no two paths cross each other simultaneously") is the [mapping class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group) of your manifold, i.e. the *isotopy* classes of diffeomorphisms of $M$. The number you seek is the cardinality of the mapping class group; I do not think this number has a special name.